# Galois group of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

How can we find the Galois group of the inseparable extension $F_p(t^p)\leq F_p(t)$? Here $t$ is a transcendental element over $Fp$.

Now I let $L = F_p(t)$, and $K = Fp(tp)$. Then clearly the extension $L/K$ is finite but inseparable, since the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K$ is $X^p − t^p$ , which splits as $(X − t)^p$ over $L[X]$. But here after I stuck. Could someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of Galois group of an inseparable extension? Usually, they are defined for Galois extensions, which are in particular separable.

Comment: If you're asking for the group of field automorphisms, observe that any field map fixes the minimal polynomial of $t$, and hence fixes $t$, since $t$ is the only root. So the map must be trivial

Comment: @Mathmo123 34 . Yes, I am asking for the group of field automorphisms. I didn't understand the map that will be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is a field automorphism of $\mathbb F_p(t)$ which fixes $\mathbb F_p(t^p)$, then in particular,
$$\sigma(t)^p-t^p=\sigma(t^p)-t^p =t^p-t^p=0,$$
so $\sigma(t)$ is also a root of $X^p-t^p$. Since this polynomial only has one root in $L$, namely $t$ itself, it follows that $\sigma(t)=t$. Hence, $\sigma$ fixes the whole of $\mathbb F_p(t)$, so must be trivial.

Comment: @Mathmo123..Thank you very much. I understand it now.